# Difference between VQ and V2Q

Tags: gf

To output a verb phrase that has an object as a question, then as it seems RGL only offers two functions:

```hs
VQ -> QS -> VP
V2Q -> NP -> QS -> VP
```

And in these two functions, the verb type was divided into two different categories. But the type `V2Q` has a parameter that requires adding a preposition to the sentence. In order to generate the sentence `Tell me who I am` I used the following code:

```hs
MySentence = {s = (mkPhr 
                      (mkImp 
                        (mkVP 
                          (mkV2Q 
                            (mkV "tell") 
                            (mkPrep "")) 
                          (i_NP) 
                          (mkQS 
                            (mkQCl 
                              (mkIComp (who_IP)) 
                              (i_NP)))))).s };
```

The code above generates the output I desire without a problem. So my question is, is there any reason the preposition was added to the verb `V2Q`？ Or was this output generated in a wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, yes you constructed the sentence correctly.

#### Why is there a slot for preposition in V2Q

In general, all V2* (and V3*) may take their NP object as a direct object, like *eat ___, see ___*, or with a preposition, like *believe in ___*.

This is more flexible than forcing all transitive verbs only take direct objects, and all prepositional phrases to be analysed as optional adverbials. Take a VP like *"believe in yourself"*, it's not that you're believing (something) and also your location is yourself. It's nice to be able to encode that `believe_V2` takes an obligatory argument, and that argument is introduced by the preposition *in*.

(Side note: for a VP like *"sleep in a soft bed"*, "in a soft bed" is **not** an obligatory argument of *sleep*. So then we just make *sleep* into an intransitive verb, `sleep_V`, and make *in a soft bed* into an Adv.)

So, this generalises to all verbs that take some NP argument (V2V, V2S, V2Q, V2A). Take a VP like *"lie [to children] [that moon is made of cheese]"*: the verb *lie* is a V2S that introduces its NP object with the preposition *to*.

In fact, many RGL languages offer a `noPrep` in their Paradigms module—you can Ctrl+F [in the RGL synopsis page](http://www.grammaticalframework.org/lib/doc/synopsis/index.html) to see examples.

#### The constructors of V2Q

So why are you forced to make your V2Q with `mkV2Q (mkV "tell") (mkPrep "")`, even when there is no preposition?

More common verb types, like V2, have several overload instances of `mkV2`. The simplest is just [`mkV2 : Str -> V2`](https://github.com/GrammaticalFramework/gf-rgl/blob/e85efec7a57fc8acfa41d13815e9dec76acd4ebc/src/english/ParadigmsEng.gf#L736). Since it's such a common thing for transitive verbs to have a direct object (i.e. not introduce their object with a preposition), and there are so many simple V2s, it would be pretty annoying to have to always specify a `noPrep` for most of them.

V2Q is rarer than V2, so nobody just hasn't bothered creating an instance that doesn't take a preposition. The constructor that takes preposition is more general than the constructor that doesn't, since you can always choose the preposition to be `noPrep`. Well, I just pushed a few new additions, see [here](https://github.com/GrammaticalFramework/gf-rgl/commit/1cc58f50481e66217db10ca44f22ccf418e1f23b), so if you get the latest RGL, you can now just do `mkV2Q "tell"`.

This kind of thing is completely customisable: if you want more overload instances of some `mkX` oper, you can just make them.